# how to install a zip package using pycharm?

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, package, window

I am trying to use sumologic-sdk package. I download the zip file from https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-python-sdk. I use pycharm to code. Now my problems is:

1. I try to use pycharm to install the package. But I have the error:

[image]

2.Because my company has security system, I can not use cmd (command prompt).

3.I have tried powershell (windows 10), but 'pip' does not work.

[image]

So, my udnerstand is I have to install the zip package in pycharm. Or maybe there is another way that I do not know. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What `pip` version do you have? Try to update `PyCharm` so it will be compatible  with installed `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 PS C:\Users\fchen4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts> .\pip.exe install sumologic-sdk
```

Using this way is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download zip file first. And then add to pycharm. You need to follow below steps.

1. Open your project in pycharm.
2. Go to setting option in File on Menu Bar.
3. Click on Project Interpreter under **Project:your_project_name**.
4. Click on **+** sign on right corner of setting dialog window.
5. Enter Your package name in search box **sumologic-sdk**.
6. Click on Install.

Note: You need an internet connection.

Comment: This is what I did in the first example. I have got the error shown in the first picture